# Overriding Qt function in classes

Tags: c++, qt, overriding, qdialog

I have a simple dialog of type `QDialog`. When the uses clicks OK button I want to do some validation before closing the form and returning to caller (main form).

I tried to add in my "CustomDialog.cpp" file the following code:

```
void CustomDialog::accept(){
  // My code...
}
```

But I get this error:

> error: virtual function 'accept' has different calling convention
>   attributes ('void ()') than the function it overrides (which has
>   calling convention 'void () **attribute**((thiscall))')

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something in the CustomDialog.hpp too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.hpp`, you should declare `accept()` method inside your `CustomDialog` class. i.e. `void accept() override;` under `public slots`.

Comment: Nice. So, what's the calling convention issue all about?